# Is there a risk of saving document in Mongo with _id from other DB?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I want to save documents to designated Mongo collection from other 3rd party API that uses Mongo too. I want to keep those id's so I would be able to check if I'm not saving duplicates.

- Is there any risk that those ids may collide one day?
- Is it possible to have isolated ObjectID generator for a specific collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(a) The likelihood is very low, but I will advise against it.

(b) Yes, it is. I can think of modifying it in the pr-save hook of your schema definition. There might also be modules out there for this.